# Ability for Community User to change Account Owner

Tags: sharing, community, ownership

Morning all,

In my org we have a private OWD sharing model with apex managed sharing granting read/write access to certain certain groups based on account settings. All accounts are owned by a generic Salesforce user account.

e.g. Customer is Mr Jones. He lives in Port Talbot. His account is owned by System User (salesforce licence) from head office. Mr Jones' record is shared to the Port Talbot partner office as they manage his account and the sharing settings grant them Read/Write access. Only internal users and community users from Port Talbot can see the record due to the OWD.

I want to allow a community user to change the ownership of an account that they have access to but have just discovered that Transfer Record is not an applicable System Permission for Partner Community licence types. Adding Read/Edit object permissions does not improve the situation I can see no other obvious route for this to be done apart from changing the ownership myself as an internal admin at the request of the community user.

Has anyone had any experience with this kind of issue and managed to resolve it?